# How to get registry value in virtual machine

Tags: java, regex, virtual-machine

I have code running in virtual machine and want to get registry in on that machine. But none of these works:

```
//First opinion
Preferences p = Preferences.userRoot();
    System.out.println("xx " + p.nodeExists("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Autotask Corporation\\Workplace\\Capabilities\\ApplicationName"));

//Second opinion
Preferences r = Preferences.systemRoot();
System.out.println("yy " + r.nodeExists("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Autotask Corporation\\Workplace\\Capabilities\\ApplicationName"));

//Third opinion
String value = WinRegistry.getString (
                WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,                                         //HKEY
                "SOFTWARE\\Autotask Corporation\\Workplace\\Capabilities",           //Key
                "ApplicationName");                                                 //ValueName
System.out.println("Windows Distribution = " + value);

//Fourth opinion
WindowsRegistry reg = WindowsRegistry.getInstance();
String tree = "SOFTWARE\\Autotask Corporation\\Workplace\\Capabilities";
try {
    String automationPortString = reg.readString(HKey.HKLM, tree, "ApplicationName");
}catch (RegistryException e){
    logger.info(e);
}
```

Output:

```
xx false
yy false
Windows Distribution = null
com.github.sarxos.winreg.RegistryException: Cannot read ApplicationName value from key SOFTWARE\Autotask Corporation\Workplace\Capabilities
```

Registry:

[image: My registry]